# C: File loop not reading right

Tags: c, string, file

So I have a program that takes user input and compares it to a specific line in a file, however the final line will always be credited as incorrect, so can someone solve this for me?, thanks.

File content (just a list of random words)

```
Baby
Milk
Car
Face
Library
Disc
Lollipop
Suck
Food
Pig
```

(libraries are stdio,conio and string)

```
char text[100], blank[100];
int c = 0, d = 0;

void space(void);

int main()
{
    int loop = 0;
    char str[512];
    char string[512];
    int line = 1;
    int dis = 1;
    int score = 0;
    char text[64];

    FILE *fd;

    fd = fopen("Student Usernames.txt", "r");   // Should be test

    if (fd == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the string: ");
        gets(text);

        while (text[c] != '\0')
        {
            if (!(text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' '))
            {
                string[d] = text[c];
                d++;
            }
            c++;
        }

 string[d] = '\0';
 printf("Text after removing blanks\n%s\n", string);

 getch();

for(loop = 0;loop<line;++loop)
{
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd);
}
printf("\nLine %d: %s\n", dis, str);
dis=dis+1;
str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
if(strcmp(string,str) == 0 )
 {
 printf("Match\n");
 score=score+2;
 }
     else
     {
     printf("Nope\n");
     score=score+1;
     }
 getch();
 c=0;
 d=0;
}
while(!feof(fd));
printf("Score: %d",score);
getch();
}
```

For any input on the last line, the output will always be incorrect, I believe this is something to do with the for loop not turning it into the next variable, but seeing as the <= notation makes this program worse, I really just need a simple fix for the program thanks.

Comment: This seems redundant: `(text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' ')`

Comment: Hell someone told me to write it so I wrote it

Comment: You can use `isblank` or `isspace` in `ctype.h`.

Comment: This works fine, it's just the final line dammit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you should correct this statement:

```
(!(text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' ')) to this:
 (!((text[c] == ' ') && (text[c] == ' ')))
```

compiler may compile both, but wont work properly in your case

Comment: Changed it, but I don't see how this fixes my other problem

Comment: I don't understand the point of checking the same element for the same value twice.

Comment: What do you mean? the first loop just removes the spaces, the next gets a value for str

Comment: Aside from the fact that performing the equality test doen't do anything, adding the parens as in your example don't change anything.  the precedence of `==` is higher than `&&`.  The parens don't hurt, but they don't help (other than maybe fpr readability, which is entirely questionable for this code anyway).

Comment: !(text[c]==' ')    EQUALS    (!(text[c]==' ')&&(text[c]==' ')=

Comment: The remove spaces function WORKS FINE. If you actually run the program you will find that the only thing that is wrong is the last line of the file, nothing else.

Comment: @user3344560 You may _think_ that the last line is the only problem, but believe me there are many others. Just because they don't show up in your particular tests doesn't mean they are not there. Anyhow, why did you accept this answer that clearly has nothing to do with the question about the last line of input?

Comment: @arkku I don't care about any other problems, they don't affect my program, it runs just fine until the last part, and that is my problem. I'm not even sure you've even ran the program on a complier, otherwise you would know that anything I've been given for all 5 of my answers don't do shit .

Comment: @user3344560: you ask a crappy, confusing question, mark an incorrect answer as solving your problem, then complain about people trying to help you. Not a great way to start off at stackoverflow.  I'm sorry that I put any time into this question.

Comment: @user3344560 Actually I did run it through the compiler and I got it working just fine after doing _all_ the changes necessary. Any one of them in isolation won't solve it, because there are many interacting bugs, e.g., if you change `gets` to `fgets` you must also fix the newline stripping, if you remove `feof` you must also start checking return values of the (now two) `fgets`, etc. But since you keep insisting that you know better than all the experienced programmers who gave their time to try and help you, surely you can come up with magic solution that “does shit”.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not cleaning off the newline from 'string' when you've done it for the input line from the file.  EG, you're doing this:

```
str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
```

But not this:

```
string[strlen(string)-1] = '\0';
```

(as a side note, you should avoid using the word 'string' in C-code just in case you ever want to port it to C++ in the future)

Comment: Didn't work, in fact I removed the strlen function to make sure it wasn't going to mess up my program